# Print External Excel File Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I Have a Excel File Which I have 5 Tabs, Say "Attachment".

And I have another Excel which I am Working, Say "Request".

So I need Quick Print One of those excel from that "Attachment" in "Request" using VBA.

Please Help!

But I saw some of them showing how to print a PDF (Not Working For Me).

```
Sub Test()

PrintFile ("C:\Test.pdf")

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the code if there is a pdf available to print and it is working with VBA

-Opens the specified pdf and prints it using the default printer

-Note that it uses the default PDF program and leaves it open

```
Sub PrintChecklistExcav_Backfill()


Dim strPth As String, strFile As String

strPth = "C:\File"
strFile = "name of document.pdf"

If Not PrintPDF(0, strPth & strFile) Then
    MsgBox "Printing failed"
End If

End Sub
```

***strPth*** for the file location

***strFile*** for the document name